# Wordpress - How to replace "-" in "|" in page title

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering if it's possible to replace the `"-"` in `"|"` in the page title.

For example, If I have a page called `"about"` it displays `"SITENAME - About"`, and I want to change it to `"SITENAME | About`.

Comment: Do you mean the actual <title></title> or a title within your page content?

Comment: there's a setting in the admin panel I believe...

Answer (score 0):

Add this on top of your `<head>` tag

```
<title><?php wp_title('-',true,'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you are getting the title in the theme. If the theme is just using something like get_the_title() you can use a simple string replace.

```
<?php echo str_replace('-', '|', get_the_title()) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_title` hook to change site title as you want. AN put this code in `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_new_site_title', 10, 2 );

function my_new_site_title($title)
{

        $title = get_bloginfo('name').'|'.$title;   
    return $title;
}
```

Or you can also use filter `add_filter()` with `the_title` hook.

```
function my_filter_wp_title( $title ) {    

    $custom_title = get_bloginfo('name').'|'.$title;

    return $custom_title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_filter_wp_title' );
```